# Euclidean division properties

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I've been asked to prove this property of integers:

> Let $\gamma$ be the remainder from the euclidean division of $n$ by $m$. Prove that the remainder from the division of $2^n-1$ by $2^m - 1$ is $2^\gamma - 1$.

She also asked me to find the quotient from this division. Can anyone help me? Tried a couple things here but couldn't figure it out myself. 
(I also already apologize for my poor math English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $n = mr + \gamma$, $r\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m>\gamma$. Using Euclidean Division:

$$
\begin{align*}
2^n-1 &= 2^{mr + \gamma}-1 \\
&= 2^{mr}\cdot 2^\gamma - 1 \\
&= 2^\gamma(2^{mr}-1)+(2^\gamma - 1) \\
&= 2^\gamma[(2^m)^r-1]+(2^\gamma - 1) \\
&= 2^\gamma\cdot (2^m - 1)\cdot[2^{m(r-1)}+2^{m(r-2)} + \ldots 2^{2m} + 2^m + 1] + (2^\gamma-1) \\
&= (2^m - 1)\cdot q + (2^\gamma - 1)
\end{align*}
$$
where $q = 2^\gamma\cdot[2^{m(r-1)}+2^{m(r-2)} + \ldots 2^{2m} + 2^m + 1]$.

Notice that if $m > \gamma$, then $2^m - 1 > 2^\gamma - 1$.

If $2^n - 1 = (2^m - 1)\cdot q + (2^\gamma - 1)$ with $2^\gamma - 1 < 2^m - 1$, then $2^\gamma-1$ is the remainder of the asked division.